# Progress Bar for calling multiple sub

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

Is there any way to create **a Process Bar in Excel VBA** as calling multiple sub? Each sub proximately took 10 minutes to copy and paste from a file to this workbook. I would like to know how long it has been processing(**completed percentage**).
I know if I have a for loop progress, I could apply progress bar for it. Don't have an idea how to loop through something like this.

```
Sub batch_import()

Call Import_NJ
Call Import_NY
Call Import_MD
Call Import_VA
Call Import_WV
Call Import_PA
Call Import_KY
Call Import_TN
Call Import_IN
Call Import_IA
Call Import_MI
Call Import_MO
Call Import_IL
Call Import_LW

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want the progress bar to update itself while inside the Import_* sub, or just between each calls?

Comment: You have 14 calls, after each call you can increase a variable by 1/14 like: `x = x + 1/14`. At the end it reaches to 1. You can display `x` however you want. (You can simply use debug.print, or if you need something for enduser, you can use a bar in the userforms)

Comment: Perhaps a bit advanced VBA stuff (involves classes, module attributes, default instances and factory methods), but an *actual* reusable, flexible, cancellable and good-looking progress indicator form is totally feasible in VBA; see [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/87818/23788).

Comment: @Vincent G I want to update inside the import as a whole process.

Comment: @Tehscript and Mat's Mug I would try that. Thanks for the useful info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always have the same amount of subs to call (ie the 14 identified). you could do

```
Sub batch_import()
with Application
    Call Import_NJ
    .StatusBar = "Progress: " & Format(1 / 14, "0%")
    Call Import_NY
    .StatusBar = "Progress: " & Format(2 / 14, "0%")
    Call Import_MD
    .StatusBar = "Progress: " & Format(3 / 14, "0%")
    Call Import_VA
    .StatusBar = "Progress: " & Format(4 / 14, "0%")
    Call Import_WV
    .StatusBar = "Progress: " & Format(5 / 14, "0%")
    Call Import_PA
    .StatusBar = "Progress: " & Format(6 / 14, "0%")
    Call Import_KY
    .StatusBar = "Progress: " & Format(7 / 14, "0%")
    Call Import_TN
    .StatusBar = "Progress: " & Format(8 / 14, "0%")
    Call Import_IN
    .StatusBar = "Progress: " & Format(9 / 14, "0%")
    Call Import_IA
    .StatusBar = "Progress: " & Format(10 / 14, "0%")
    Call Import_MI
    .StatusBar = "Progress: " & Format(11 / 14, "0%")
    Call Import_MO
    .StatusBar = "Progress: " & Format(12 / 14, "0%")
    Call Import_IL
    .StatusBar = "Progress: " & Format(13 / 14, "0%")
    Call Import_LW
    .StatusBar = "Progress: " & Format(14 / 14, "0%")
    .StatusBar =null
end with
End Sub
```

Comment: I would try this!! It looks really simple to understand and run.

Comment: Hey,@Dude_Scott. While I am typing this. The process bar is running as smoothly as it can. Thanks for the tips! However, what if I want it to stop?

Comment: Change the .StatusBar = null to .StatusBar =false